# MaterializeCSS disable specific dates

Tags: date, datepicker, materialize

I'm trying to disable the weekends (saturdays and sundays) and some dates (like '2018-05-11', '2018-05-21', '2018-05-24', etc.) in MaterializeCSS datepicker, but I want to disable those dates every year. I'm able to disable the days and dates with

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
       disable: [
            1, 7, new Date(2018,5,11), {from: [2018,5,11], to: [2018,5,22]}, {from: [2018,8,5], to: [2018,8,17]}
       ]
});
```

So I want to know if there's a way to made it repeat every year.

Answer (score 0):

[materializecss pickers](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)

You can customize which days are disabled with the `disableDayFn` option when initializing the datepicker. This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeyOmX) shows an example of the `disableDayFn` option being used to disable weekends, May 11th, 21st, and 24th of every year.

Comment: That's what I did, but I wanna know if there's a way to repeat them every year forever without the need to specify every year in the array

Comment: Whoops! I forgot to get the new URL after forking the CodePen. I've updated my answer. [Correct CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeyOmX)

Comment: Corrected syntax issues from original codepan [link] (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqbXwE)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.disablePast').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 105, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Ok',
        format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        closeOnSelect: true,
        min : true
    });
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 105, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Ok',
        format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        closeOnSelect: true,

        onSet: function(context) {
            var id = this.$node[0].id;
            var d = new Date(context.select);
            var dd = d.getDate();
            var mm = d.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

            var yyyy = '';
            yyyy = new Date().getFullYear();
            year1=yyyy;
            month1=mm;
            if(dd<10){
                dd='0'+dd;
            } 
            if(mm<10){
                mm='0'+mm;
            } 
            var df = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
            var msec = Date.parse(df);
            var d1 = new Date();
            var d2 = new Date(msec);
            var timeDiff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            var DaysDiff = timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
            var dff = '';
            var dft = '';
            if(DaysDiff >= 0){
                dff = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
            } else{
                yyyy = yyyy + 1;
                dff = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
            }




             if(month1==1) 
             {
                year1 = year1 - 1;


                month1 = 12;

            }
            else if(month1<=10)
            {
                month1=month1-1;
                month1='0'+month1;
            }
            else
            {
                month1=month1-1;
            }
            dft = dd+'/'+month1+'/'+year1;








            /*if(df > 0){
                dft = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
            }
            // if(mm = 01) {
            //     mm = 12;
            //     yyyy = yyyy - 1;
            //     dft = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
            // }
             else{
                yyyy = yyyy + 1;
                mm = mm - 1;
                dft = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
            }*/
             console.log(dft);
            if(id == 'dob')
                $('#dob_rem_on').val(dff);
            if(id == 'aniv_date')
                $('#aniv_rem_on').val(dff);
            if(id == 'passport_ren')
                $('#pass_rem_on').val(dft);
            if(id == 'insurance_ren')
                $('#insurance_rem_on').val(dft);
            if(id == 'life_insurance_ren')
                $('#life_insurance_rem_on').val(dft);
            Materialize.updateTextFields();
        }    
});
```